# Add Crystal Reports to Spring Boot REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, crystal-reports

I have a requirement to run Crystal Reports exports from a Spring Boot REST application

I have the latest Crystal Reports for Eclipse plugin and a Crystal Reports project that is successful processing a PDF/MSEXCEL export of a *.rpt file

What I can't figure out is how to include this in a Spring Boot application.

The Crystal Reports java project includes a Crystal Reports build path library that includes a list of Jars provided by the plug-in

I have googled how I might find a straight forward way to create the required Maven dependencies for this eclipse build path library.  I have not found anything.

Looking at the build path library, I see jars that may already be provided, like some Apache commons.* jars

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, For a Spring Boot project, you need to define your own Maven dependencies of any dependencies. SAP does not publish Crystal Reports to Maven Central